# How can I get my length and width to represented in a string format?

Tags: java, tostring

I was wondering if I could get some help with my length and width. I dont know how to get them into the format of being a string. I thought about the toString() idea, but then I think I would need a char value for that. Any help would be amazing.

```
public class Rectangle
{
// instance variables 
private int length;
private int width;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
 */
public Rectangle(int l, int w)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

// return the height
public int getLength()
{
    return length;
}
public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public String String()
{
    return System.out.println(length + " X " + width);
   }
```

}

Comment: I have the answer now, thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your String() method to `toString()` which I overrided. This  method is used when we need a string representation of an object. It is defined in `Object` class. This method can be overridden to customize the String representation of the Object.You can check this

```
public class Rectangle
{
    // instance variables 
    private int length;
    private int width;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
     */
    public Rectangle(int l, int w)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }

    // return the height
    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
         return length + " X " + width;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
          Rectangle test = new Rectangle(3, 4);
          System.out.println(test.toString());
       }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd explain what you changed and why, rather than just dumping the code.

Comment: This really helped me out for future use, thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Rename `String()` method to `toString()` (the method that normally returns an  object string representation) and return from it `length + " X " + width`.

You can use `String` as a method name, but it violates JCC and looks abnormally.

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
> lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
>
> Examples:
>
> run();
> runFast();
> getBackground();

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 public class Rectangle {


    // instance variables
    private int length;
    private int width;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
     */
    public Rectangle(int l, int w)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }

    // return the height
    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return length + " X " + width;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(8, 9);
        System.out.println(rec.toString());
    }
}
```